# Tesseract.NET SDK messing up some numbers

Tags: c#, tesseract

I'm trying to have Tesseract.NET SDK parse out Fortnite replay grid image. It does a pretty good job, but the last elim count it gave an A instead of 4, which is odd because it got the 4 elims in the above line right. That would be able to be worked around as I get a 4 can look like an A so I could check and switch. However the big one is that it say the 6th place finish as a 3rd place which is the big show stopper. I'm completely new to Tesseract so I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to get higher confidence for such a specific example as all images will look like this. The idea is I'm using placement and elimination values for points in a tourney that I would like to automate calculating.

```
 using (var api = OcrApi.Create())
            {
                api.Init(@"C:\Users\MyUsername\source\repos\FnTourneyReader\FnTourneyReader", "eng");
                string plainText = api.GetTextFromImage(@"C:\Users\MyUsername\source\repos\FnTourneyReader\FnTourneyReader\Content\TourneyTest.png");

                var matches = plainText.Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));

                foreach(var match in matches)
                {
                    var details = match.Split(' ');

                    if (details[0] == "DATE")
                        continue;

                    var placement = details[4].Split('/')[0];
                    var elims = details[5];
                }
            }
```

Text comes through like:

"DATE LENGTH FINISH ELIMINATIONS\n7/11/20, 11:53 PM 22:21 4/99 2\n7/11/20, 11:35 PM 19:37 7/93 1\n7/11/20, 11:03 PM 23:10 1/99 2\n7/11/20, 10:43 PM 22:12 3/95 4\n7/11/20, 12:40 PM 23:14 1/98 A\n\n"

[image]

Comment: Convert all blue pixels to black and non blue to white, then try the ocr again. High contrast works best in my experience.

Comment: @Mikael Tried that and while it was better for sure, now the 8 in the 98 is read as a 3 so 93. Makes me concerned that an 8th place will be seen as a 3rd place which has tournament implications.

Comment: You can try to add a slight blur on the text, sometimes that helps. I've messed with several of the OCR libraries and haven't found any to be 100% accurate all of the time. The paid ones ARE better (again, in my experience) but still make mistakes here and there. Keep playing with stuff and you may get it accurate enough for your needs.